# Debian 8 openjdk-8-jre-headless installation fail

Tags: linux, debian, java, jre, openjdk

I have a VM I'm using to test out things with tomcat8. Since, my PC has java8 installed (and I personally don't want to fall back to java7), I tried installing JRE 1.8 on the "server" vm. Since I'm running Debian 8 (Jessie), I looked into how to install and came to the conclusion (looking at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/830636/cannot-install-openjdk-8-jre-headless-on-debian-jessie), for example) that I had to use

```
sudo apt-get install -t jessie-backports openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

But when I do that, I get the following error message (which looks like an HTTP error to me):

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
openjdk-8-jre-headless is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libfontenc1 libxfont1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 130 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u121-1~webupd8~2) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
converted 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u121-b13/e9e7ea248e2c4826b92b3f075a80e441/jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u121-b13/e9e7ea248e2c4826b92b3f075a80e441/jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz' (UTF-8)
--2017-03-23 12:03:57--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u121-b13/e9e7ea248e2c4826b92b3f075a80e441/jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 95.101.114.65,95.101.114.75
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|95.101.114.65|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u121-b13/e9e7ea248e2c4826b92b3f075a80e441/jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
converted 'https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u121-b13/e9e7ea248e2c4826b92b3f075a80e441/jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u121-b13/e9e7ea248e2c4826b92b3f075a80e441/jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz' (UTF-8)
--2017-03-23 12:03:58--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u121-b13/e9e7ea248e2c4826b92b3f075a80e441/jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 2.23.14.19, 2001:41a8:26:18b::2d3e, 2001:41a8:26:19d::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2.23.14.19|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2001:41a8:26:18b::2d3e|:443... failed: Network is unreachable.
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2001:41a8:26:19d::2d3e|:443... failed: Network is unreachable.
download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
  Errors were encountered while processing:
   oracle-java8-installer
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

From your apt-get output it is clear that JRE 8 from OpenJDK is already installed.

The failure is caused by different package - oracle-java8-installer. It fails to download required files, probably because you cancelled the installation and newer version is already available.

If you don't want that package, remove it with `apt-get remove <pkg>`. if you want Oracle JDK installed side-by-side with OpenJDK, then you should remove it as well, do `apt-get update` and finally `apt-get install <pkg>` to receive newer installation scripts.